# MobileFirst container is stuck in my Bluemix space though I deleted it

Tags: ibm-cloud

I created a container using the evaluation image for Mobile First (built an image and pushed it), then deleted the container. Though I deleted that container, it still shows in my Dashboard with state "Unknown". What is worse is that it is taking 1 GB of memory out of my 2 GB quota. So, I am not able to create a new container with memory >= 1GB nor am I able to delete the "Unknown" state one. I tried to log out or use different browser with no luck.

The result of "ice ps" is zero rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
ice ps
```

returns only running containers.

Please try to run the following command

```
ice ps -a
```

This one lists all containers in your space.

If you see your container listed use the following command to remove it:

```
ice rm <container id> --force
```

In case this solution does not work for you then I suggest you to open a ticket with IBM Bluemix Support and someone in support can help you delete the container. Here is the link to create a support ticket:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#support

Comment: ice ps -a showed the container and I could delete it using --force. Thank you very much @adasilva70 for your help.